# Why is a discounted price process a local martingale under the Risk Neutral Measure?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

I'm familiar with the fact that if the stochastic process $\left( g(t) \right)_{t \in \left[0 , T \right]}$ is almost surely square integrable, i.e. $\mathbb{P}\left(  \int_0^t |g(s)|^2ds < \infty \right)=1 , \ \forall t \in \left[ 0, T \right]$, then the process $  \left( \int_0^t g(s)dW(s)\right)_ {t \in \left[0 , T \right]}$ is a continuous local martingale, where $W(t)$ is a Wiener process.

Furthermore, in the model market the risk-free asset $B$ is modeled as 
$$dB(t)=B(t)r(t)dt,$$
where $r(t)$ is adapted and a.s. integrable, and the risky assets $S_1,S_2, \dots, S_m$ are modelled as
$$dS_i(t)=S_i(t) \left[  \mu_i(t)dt+\sum_{j=1}^n \sigma_{ij}(t)dW_j(t) \right],$$
where $\mu_i(t)$ is adapted and a.s. integrable and $\sigma_{ij}(t)$ is adapted and a.s. square integrable.

Then, under the risk neutral measure $\mathbb{Q}$, for the discounted price process $P_i(t)=\frac{S_i(t)}{B(t)}$ we have
$$dP_i(t)=P_i(t)\sum_{j=1}^n\sigma_{ij}(t)dW_j^{\mathbb{Q}}(t).$$

What I don't understand is why is the discounted price process local martingale under the risk neutral measure $\mathbb{Q}$. Integrands of the stochastic integrals on the RHS of the last equality are of the following form: $P_i(t)\sigma_{ij}(t)$, so how can we automatically know that those itegrands are a.s. square integrable, what is needed in order for a stochastic integral to be a local martingale.

I've tried proving that $P_i(t)$ (discounted price process) is a local martingale by first solving SDE of its dynamics and getting

$$P_i(t)=P_i(0)e^{\int_0^t(-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^n \sigma^2_{ij}(s))ds + \sum_{j=0}^n\int_0^t \sigma_{ij}(s)dW_j(s)},$$
and then trying to prove that this process is a local martingale. I know how to do it when I assume that $\sigma_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}$, but I don't know how to do it in a general case.

Thanks for any hint on this!

Comment: I would have a look at theorems on solutions to SDE if I were you, the properties of those solutions might give you what you are looking for. Best regards